# Converting MPP files to MS XML format in Python using MPXJ

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, jpype, mpxj

I am trying to convert MPP file to MS XML format using MPXJ library and Jpype

```
def convert(inputFile, outputFile):
   reader = ProjectReaderUtility.getProjectReader(inputFile)
   project = ProjectFile()
   project = reader.read(inputFile)
   writer = ProjectWriter
   writer = ProjectWriterUtility.getProjectWriter(outputFile)
   writer.write(project, outputFile)
```

This works fine if I try to convert to json format. However, there is always an error related to xml file. I get an error related to java xml library

```
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
```

Would anyone be able to assist in this issue.
I am using Python 3.8 with jdk-15.0.2

Comment: What version of MPXJ are you working with?

Comment: ... and as a followup to that, how do you configure JPype to pick up the MPXJ jar and its dependencies?

Comment: I am using MXPJ version 9.0.0
For the configuration I have loaded the jar files 
import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *
from collections import defaultdict
import sys
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea")
jpype.addClassPath("mpxj-9.0.0.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("poi-5.0.0.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("commons-math3-3.6.1.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("commons-collections4-4.4.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("SparseBitSet-1.2.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("commons-codec-1.15.jar")

Comment: jpype.addClassPath("rtfparserkit-1.16.0.jar")
jpype.addClassPath("jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar")

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a wrong dependency as inspired by Jon Illes response. I was using jaxb-api which isn't the correct dependency. After checking the list of dependency, I learnt that the correct package required is jaxb-runtime. After downloading it the script works.

Thanks Jon for the prompt response and directing to the solution

Comment: Hi Hassan, I was inspired by your question to create a package for this, hopefully it'll make MPXJ easier to consume from Python. https://pypi.org/project/mpxj/

Comment: Hi Jon,
That is brilliant and I would love to contribute (if there is a need for further development) to it as I have started an open source package myself to parse XER files only. It is still in very early stages but it does help.
https://github.com/HassanEmam/PyP6Xer